# MOSFET Driving On The Cheap And Cheerful

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, capacitance, charge-pump

I need (unless I'm XYing) to high side switch a FET pair from a (PIC16) microcontroller in the simplest way possible. They are switching an audio line with significant current (presently the output of an LM386 running at 5V single rail). I've been noodling about trying to think of the simplest way to do this with the lowest part count/cost/board space etc. The switching does not need to be fast and will only happen occasionally when my device switches modes due to different audio sources being connected. This isn't audiophile level concerns. It's running headphones mainly for speech of telephony quality.

So, high side switching with current in the potentially low hundreds of mA needs a good voltage on the gate above the 5V. So, a voltage doubler. For reasons stated above and also somewhat a matter of taste I want to avoid yet another transistor in the mix. So I realised a simple voltage doubler (with which I have little practical experience) seems to be the answer. After fiddling with that, I realised I could actually use the FETs' gate capacitance as one of the capacitors in my doubler. So, this circuit-

[image: Schematic with resistors]

D1 and D2 are the doubler diodes, C1 is the cap that isn't the FET gates. V2 represents a microcontroller pin running at about 100kHz for a clock. V3 is another pin which goes high or low to enable the output to drive fully up to 9ish volts and down to nearly zero. M1,M2,C3 and RLoad are the FEts and their load. R2 discharges the charge pump when it switches off. The FETs are actually switched by a combination of (a) the charge pump running and (b) V3 going high. According to the simulator btw, if I change my diodes to 1n5817 Schottkys, their reverse leakage is sufficient to not need R2, so that's another component saved. The output looks like this-

[image]

So what I'm primarily asking about here is R1 and R3. Their only purpose is to limit the current pulsing out of the MCU pins. With them in circuit, the spikes are entirely within the PIC spec at a few mA. Worst case is (not surprisingly) when the charge pump starts running.

If I take them out of the circuit, I save 2 resistors but the current now looks like this-

[image]

Ouch. However, this are extremely short spikes of current going into a capacitance of 4.7nF (plus the gate capacitances).

[image]

...the spacing being 5 microseconds (100kHz) and the spike pulse length being about 50ns. Basically I'm not sure how much an MCU pin can cope with short capacitive spikes like this before blowing; or over what time interval (if any) the current rating holds good.

Can I get away without the resistors? Any other thoughts on this? Are MCUs tolerant of capacitive loading? Am I in Rube Goldberg territory? I'm in that situation where the circuit I'm working on in general (of which this is only a part) is just looking too complexificated and I'm trying to pare it down.

I've had a good read of the datasheets for the PIC but I can't find a spec for capacitive loading of the pins.

NB yes there is a particular circuit reason I want to switch the amplifier's output before the 220uF DC blocking capacitor, by the way.

Comment: Are you looking for something able to handle currents on the level of this device: http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NLAS4157-D.PDF ?

Comment: Would a good old mechanical relay solve your problem?

Comment: jonk- TBH I'm trying to avoid SMT at the moment as I don't have the facilities for working with them. That's a nice chip though isn't it? Nick- I've thought about a mechanical relay, but I'm not really confident about reliability. Also, relays are quite big.

Comment: It would be much, much easier to use PMOS. No pump required.

Comment: Mkeith, same problem. My AC signal can go close to either rail. So I then need a negative charge pump...

Comment: Then use Jonk's part. It is not expensive.

Comment: I'm interested in the capacitance question anyway, please. Plus the part doesn't quite do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You say your are driving headphones. This is why I initially thought the voltage swing would be small and you could get away with using PMOS. But I guess you are driving a loudspeaker, right? If you really are driving headphones, you don't want to have 5V peak to peak.

Comment: To answer your main question, I do not think you have modeled the output of the micro-controller accurately enough with V2. I don't think you can trust any response excited by V2 unless you come up with a better model. But, I doubt that you are going to blow up your micro output.

Comment: Indeed, I don't trust the simulator since I don't have a model of the MCU. That's why I asked :)

Comment: You are quite right, you are XYing so much. It is much simpler having an array audio amplifier with individual enable, one for each headphone you need. This will be both lower part count and better performance.

Comment: Well, any time you see 1A coming out of a standard uC IO pin, you should pause to consider if there might be a problem. IO pins have series resistance (although it is not very accurate to model them as voltage source with series resistance, it is better than what you have now).

Comment: I did pause and, having no model for the MCU, that is why I asked here about anyone's experience with capacitive loading of (PIC) MCU pins. I have no model for the actual output resistance/impedance, nor any detailed characterisation of heating effects (and stuff I don't understand about charge migration or whatnot in the output fets of the MCU, nor any characterisation of said FETs). So I thought I'd ask. But sadly everyone decided to redesign the circuit instead. Maybe nobody knows. I guess I'll just have to stick it on a breadboard and test to destruction.

Comment: Usually you would use a vendor supplied spice model. Is one available? There is also a model specifically for digital circuits called an IBIS model. Can you get one of those for the IC? If not, you can scrutinize the electrical data in the datasheet and you may be able to infer an approximate series resistance. It would be something like 10 Ohms, but it is not constant. It varies throughout the switching cycle. When I said you should pause, I mean not out of fear of damage, but you should just have a reality check. Can the output transistor actually deliver an amp? The answer is, no.

Comment: If a reactive (inductive) load caused an output current of 1A, the voltage slew rate would be extremely large, and there would be an over/under voltage that would probably damage the IC.

Comment: Hi Mkeith, yes I know it can't deliver that. Hence my wondering what is actually likely to happen with a real capacitance on an output pin. For instance, if I connect a FET gate directly to an MCU pin, it is a capacitor. It will thus cause a current surge which will be above the current rating of the pin. But it works. People do it every day. I do. So I was hoping one of the contributors here has some actual experience/advice with capacitive loading of this kind, on a PIC or similar MCU.

Comment: Get an IBIS model or a spice model. Turn off your computer and go to the lab with an oscilloscope and a current probe. And have a nice day.